# How to check variable value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With using the code below clicking on button **asc** should result in hiding button **asc** and showing instead button **desc** and then alert the value. And when clicking on button **desc**, `show()` should be executed for button **asc** and `hide()` for button **desc**. And the value should be displayed again in an alert message.

How can I get this behavior?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form_content">
    <button id="desc" name="desc" value="desc" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">desc</button>
    <button id="asc" name="asc" value="asc" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" style="display:none;">asc</button>
</form>

<script>
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    var content = clicked_id;
    if (var content = asc) {
        $('#asc').hide();
        $('#desc').show();
    }
    if (var content = desc) {
        $('#asc').show();
        $('#desc').hide();
    }
    alert(content);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks correct except that your asc and desc should be in quotes.  Otherwise it's going to think it's a variable.  You are also re-declaring content when you're checking it, which will likely generate an error (lose the var).

Comment: `if(var content = asc)` should be `if(content === 'asc')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (content === 'asc') {
    $('#asc').hide();
    $('#desc').show();
}
if (content === 'desc') {
    $('#asc').show();
    $('#desc').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you compare string values in javascript is with the === operator. Since the id of the element you're looking for is a string in your if statements try this:

```
if(content === 'asc')
```

and:

```
if(content === 'desc')
```

this compares the id to the string 'asc' and the string 'desc'.

The === operator means equal value and equal type, so it checks if the var on the left is of the same type (string in this case) and the same value as the var on the right.

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure of what you need, but try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kg005f4v/

```
<form method="post" id="form_content" action="Javascript:void(0);">
    <button id="desc" name="desc" value="desc">desc</button>
    <button id="asc" name="asc"  value="asc">asc</button>
</form>

#desc{
    display:none
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_content button').click(function(){
        $('#form_content button').toggle();
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```